# Unity C# | Problema Usando For Loop dentro do Update()

Tags: c#, for, unity3d

Olá,

Meu problema é o seguinte, tenho uma lista de eventos que acontecem em um tempo determinado, que é aleatorio, e quando um evento ocorre é sorteado um novo timer para o proximo adicionando mais 10 segundos, todos os eventos estão sendo chamados, o problema é que aparentemente o for está pulando o index algumas vezes, por exemplo, a lista é `{"TV","Carro","Vaso", "Armario"}` o primeiro evento a ser chamado deveria ser a TV, mas na verdade está sendo chamado o Vaso, em seguida Armario, depois a TV e o Carro.
Acredito que seja algo envolvendo a quantidade de frames chamados no update, mas não consegui encontrar nada que resolvesse.

Obrigado.

```
void Update()
    {

        Check = EventTrigger.Check;

        if(FinalEvents != null)
        for(int i = 0; i < FinalEvents.Count; i++)
        {

            if(FinalEvents[i] == "TV" && Check)
            {
                Timer -= Time.deltaTime;
                print(Timer);

                if (Timer <= 0)
                {
                    print("TV");
                    video.Play();
                    distances.CheckFear(GameObject.Find("Cenario/TV"), GameObject.Find("Player"), slider);
                    Timer = Random.Range(1, 2) + 10f;
                    i++;
                }

            }else

            if (FinalEvents[i] == "Carro" && Check)
            {
                Timer -= Time.deltaTime;
                print(Timer);

                if (Timer <= 0)
                {
                    print("Carro");
                    anim.SetTrigger("btn1");
                    distances.CheckFear(GameObject.Find("Cenario/Carrinho"), GameObject.Find("Player"), slider);
                    Timer = Random.Range(1, 2) + 10f;
                    i++;
                }

            }else

            if (FinalEvents[i] == "Armario" && Check)
            {
                Timer -= Time.deltaTime;
                print(Timer);

                if (Timer <= 0)
                {
                    print("Arm");
                    distances.CheckFear(GameObject.Find("Cenario/guardaroupas"), GameObject.Find("Player"), slider);
                    Timer = Random.Range(1, 2) + 10f;
                    i++;
                }

            }else

            if (FinalEvents[i] == "Vaso" && Check)
            {
                Timer -= Time.deltaTime;
                print(Timer);

                if (Timer <= 0)
                {
                    print("Vaso");
                    distances.CheckFear(GameObject.Find("Cenario/vaso"), GameObject.Find("Player"), slider);
                    Timer = Random.Range(1, 2) + 10f;
                    i++;
                }

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Se a idéia era ter um contador que dispare o evento depois de um certo tempo, basta colocar a linha `Timer -= Time.deltaTime;` antes do laço. Agora eu vejo um problema com a lista de eventos, ela é fixa? Como ela é preenchida? Porque vc faz um laço e obrigatoriamente, se a lista for fixa na forma que vc passou, vai passar sempre nos quatro eventos (e consequentemente subtraindo o contador do tempo por pelo menos quatro vezes em um único frame)

Comment: Acho que entendi, então o for entra nos quatro eventos por que ele completa o laço todo frame, né? Eu quero chamar o próximo item da lista só quando o timer do primeiro acaba, será que usando um foreach seria mais eficaz?

PS: A lista é fixa, mas é aleatorizada no Start()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu método `Update()` precisa saber qual evento vai executar de antemão, minha sugestão é criar uma váriavel que controle qual evento será executado, segue código:

```
int proxEvento = 0; // inicializa para o primeiro item da lista de eventos
void Update()
{

    Check = EventTrigger.Check;
    Timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (Timer <= 0)
    {
        if(FinalEvents != null && proxEvento < 4 /*Aqui vc vai querer trocar o 4 pelo Length ou Count (não sei se FinalEvents é Array ou List<>*/)
        {
            if(FinalEvents[proxEvento] == "TV" && Check)
            {
                print(Timer);

                print("TV");
                video.Play();
                distances.CheckFear(GameObject.Find("Cenario/TV"), GameObject.Find("Player"), slider);
                Timer = Random.Range(1, 2) + 10f;
                proxEvento++;
            }else

            if (FinalEvents[proxEvento] == "Carro" && Check)
            {
                print(Timer);

                print("Carro");
                anim.SetTrigger("btn1");
                distances.CheckFear(GameObject.Find("Cenario/Carrinho"), GameObject.Find("Player"), slider);
                Timer = Random.Range(1, 2) + 10f;
                proxEvento++;                

            }else

            if (FinalEvents[proxEvento] == "Armario" && Check)
            {
                print(Timer);

                print("Arm");
                distances.CheckFear(GameObject.Find("Cenario/guardaroupas"), GameObject.Find("Player"), slider);
                Timer = Random.Range(1, 2) + 10f;
                proxEvento++;
            }else

            if (FinalEvents[proxEvento] == "Vaso" && Check)
            {
                print(Timer);

                print("Vaso");
                distances.CheckFear(GameObject.Find("Cenario/vaso"), GameObject.Find("Player"), slider);
                Timer = Random.Range(1, 2) + 10f;
                proxEvento++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```